# Get Maximum value of a column in mysql DB

Tags: mysql, sql

My DB table column values are

```
tenant_ id  group_id
2           2-100
2           2-111
1           1-222
1           1-888
2           2-999 
2           2-1000
```

Query :

```
select max(group_id) from prospect_group where tenant_id=2
```

I have used the above query to get the max value for tenant_id=2 but it returns the value as 999 instead of 1000. How to get 1000 as the max value.??? Can anyone help me..???

Comment: is group_id a varchar column? If so, you should convert it into integer and then run MAX() on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT tenant_ID, MAX(CAST(group_ID AS SIGNED))
FROM tableName
-- WHERE  tenant_id=2 -- uncomment this if you select only for specific tenant_ID
GROUP BY tenant_ID
```

try it by replacing to an empty char.

```
SELECT tenant_ID, 
       MAX(CAST(REPLACE(group_ID, CONCAT(tenant_ID, '-'), '')  AS SIGNED)) maxGID
FROM tableName
-- WHERE  tenant_id=2 -- uncomment this if you select only for specific tenant_ID
GROUP BY tenant_ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9069/2)

Comment: How would this solve the OP's problem? I think GROUP BY is redundant in his case and if the column was integer, it would have returned 1000 which seems to be not the case.

Comment: ya it works but mow as per my requirement i changed my table.can u h elp for above issue?

Comment: @Baskar what do you changed the table?

Comment: @Baskar since your columns is `varchar`, you need to cast it first to numeric.

Comment: my group_id present format is 2-1000 and type is varchar.How to cast?

Comment: what is to inyour `2-1000` is it still the value of `tenant_ id`?

Comment: yes buddy it works exactly as per my requirement.Thank you johnWoo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select max(group_id) from prospect_group where tenant_id=2 group by tenant_ id
```

Comment: ya it works but mow as per my requirement i changed my table data.can u h elp for above issue?